# Call Azure Function with Private Endpoint, from Action group?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-alerts

I have an Azure Function which decides some logic surrounding scaling for an SKU that doesn't support autoscale.

I have an alert which triggers an action group, based on criteria i may want to scale by.
This action group contains a call to an Azure Function, which does the actual work.

The Azure Function is behind a Private Endpoint, and uses a host key to secure the function against unauthorised usage.
If i call the Azure Function from my trusted network (VNet Integration), i am able to get it working.
If i try to use the Action Group, it does not work, and returns a 403 Forbidden response.

My question is - is this a supported use case, and if so - how should i configure it?

EDIT: All resources reside in the same Resource Group.

Comment: Check this article that shows how to properly trigger an Azure Function from Monitor->Action Group. I am not sure but from what u present they are not in the same Resource Group and that is why u get 403. https://www.cloudsma.com/2019/09/azure-monitor-alert-azure-functions/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Updated the post to relfect resource group scope. The aciton groups are setup correctly.

Comment: did you get an answer to this question? I run into the same issue with private Logic Apps and Automation accounts. It looks like action groups are not able to talk to private resources.

Comment: No, sorry. I ended up redisgning the solution and using an SKU that supported autoscale.

Comment: Microsoft support have confirmed that this scenario is not supported for Automation Accounts and Logic Apps. I'm pretty sure it is the same for Function Apps. Action groups, however, can trigger Event Hubs that are behind a private endpoint. So in theory you could put an Event Hub in between. Action Group would send the event to an Event Hub. A Function App then would consume that event from the Event Hub.